# C remove element from dynamic array

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to write the equivalent of `remove` for Java's `ArrayList` in C.

Here is my code. It assumes that index is a valid index in the list.

```
void arrayListRemove(ArrayList* list, int index){
  int i;
  if (arrayListSize(list)==1){
    list->size = 0;
    free(list->data);
    list->data = NULL;
  } else {
    for(i=index;i<arrayListSize(list)-1;i++){
      list->data[i] = list->data[i+1];
    }
    list->data = realloc(list->data, (arrayListSize(list) - 1) * sizeof(void*));
    if (list->data != NULL){
      --list->size;
    } else {
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Is this correct?

Would the code work without the `arrayListSize(list) == 1` check? I.e. does `realloc(list->data, 0)` free the arrayList? I've seen conflicting things online about what `realloc(ptr, 0)` would do.

Comment: "Is this correct" covers a lot of ground.  Do you have any specific questions, like "why does this crash on line X for input Y", or "could this be made faster", etc.?

Comment: Would the code work without the arrayListSize(list) == 1 check? ie. does realloc(list->data, 0) free the arrayList? I've seen conflicting things online about what realloc(0) would do.

Comment: Note: you could avoid the explicit loop by using memmove(). And you could replace the `sizeof(void*)` by `sizeof list->data[0]`. If the list is unordered, it is cheaper to replace the deleted element by the last element in the array. Finally: if index is beyond the size, you still decrement the size, which looks wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I would leave the `arrayListSize(list) == 1` case. Not relying on the behavior of `realloc(ptr, 0)` seems prudent,  and it makes the code clearer, generally and by using an explicit `free`.

A few more notes:

- When using `realloc`, be sure to capture the return value in a `tmp` variable. If `realloc` fails, then it can return `NULL` and leave the original pointer untouched. By doing `ptr = realloc(ptr);` you can cause a memory leak when `realloc` fails, because you've now lost your original pointer. Instead use this idiom:

  ```
  tmp = realloc(ptr, newSize);
  if (tmp != NULL)
      ptr = tmp;
  else handleError();
  ```
- Is it necessary to `free` the elements of your list when removing them from the list? Your `data` array consists of pointers, are you leaking memory by not calling `free` on removed elements? Naturally this isn't necessary in the java implementation. If your list contains the only reference to the contained objects, then you'll need to `free` them upon remove, *or* return the pointer in your function and leave it up to the caller to deal with the memory.
- There's typically no need to use `realloc` for shrinking a list, unless you're on a platform that is **really** memory constrained, and even then, it's probably unnecessary to shrink allocated blocks for *every* deleted list element. Prefer to grow/shrink your allocated blocks by more than a single element.
- This is really a nit, but since this is an API method, and you're using a `size` member of your data structure to track the list length, you might as well use `size` throughout, rather than relying on another API method `arrayListSize`.

Comment: Going to also add a comment in that, if you are emulating Java's arraylist functionality, they don't shrink the array, only decrement the number of elements contained